# Correcting margin/padding in Wordpress CSS

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Modding a WP theme - Completely baffled as to where I am supposed to adjust the top and bottom padding for the nav.

I don't know if I am missing it in the wrapper, nav class, or the "gimmick" class below it?

demo1.dev-rlm.com

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Found it. Always remember to also look in the li > a

And for those driving themselves bananas with a similar issue, don't forget to look at selector classes like :before and :after!